# polyline linking tool without a node

Tags: gojs

I am currently using polygondrawingtool to draw polylines. Currently when the line is drawn, there will be no indication of where the first and the last point of the line is for reference. I have studied this snippet of code from the forum website but have been unsuccessful with integrating it with the drawing tool

```
function DisconnectedLinkingTool() {
    go.LinkingTool.call(this);
    this.isUnconnectedLinkValid = true;
    this._fakeStartPort = null;
  }
```

This is how i tried to initialize the disconnectedlinkingtool:

```
function mode(draw, polygon) {
      // assume PolygonDrawingTool is the first tool in the mouse-down-tools list
      var tool = myDiagram.toolManager.mouseDownTools.elt(0);

var tool = myDiagram.toolManager.mouseDownTools.elt(0);
myDiagram.toolManager.mouseDownTools.add(DisconnectedLinkingTool())

      tool.isEnabled = draw;
      tool.isPolygon = polygon;
      tool.archetypePartData.fill = (polygon ? "yellow" : null);
      tool.temporaryShape.fill = (polygon ? "yellow" : null);
    }
```

Where am i doing it wrongly?

Comment: Do you want the user to draw a new link or a new node? PolygonDrawingTool is for new nodes, PolylineLinkingTool is for new links.

Comment: i would like to draw a new node but with the adjustable  rectangles as seen with the polylinelinkingtook when clicked. Would creating a shape inside the node template be the way? Or am i getting it wrong.?

Answer (score 0):

https://gojs.net/latest/extensions/PolygonDrawing.html demonstrates how the user can draw a polygon. Note that that sample uses two different extension tools: the **PolygonDrawingTool** and the **GeometryReshapingTool**.  The former lets the user draw a new polygon by clicking where the corners should be, and the latter allows the user to move any one of those corners afterwards when the user has selected that Node.  Both tools depend on the node template and the node data having a suitable design and suitable data properties.

Depending on which module system and language you are using, the tools are at:
https://gojs.net/latest/extensions/PolygonDrawingTool.js
https://gojs.net/latest/extensionsJSM/PolygonDrawingTool.js
https://gojs.net/latest/extensionsTS/PolygonDrawingTool.ts

https://gojs.net/latest/extensions/GeometryReshapingTool.js
https://gojs.net/latest/extensionsJSM/GeometryReshapingTool.js
https://gojs.net/latest/extensionsTS/GeometryReshapingTool.ts

The sample https://gojs.net/latest/extensions/PolygonDrawing.html shows how to initialize both tools and a model data design and a node template design that works for those tools.